# Get url of public accessible s3 object using boto3 without expiration or security info

Tags: python, boto3

Running a line like:

```
s3_obj = boto3.resource('s3').Object(bucket, key)
s3_obj.meta.client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', ExpiresIn=0, Params={'Bucket':bucket,'Key':key})
```

Yields a result like:

```
https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/my-key/my-object-name?AWSAccessKeyId=SOMEKEY&Expires=SOMENUMBER&x-amz-security-token=SOMETOKEN
```

For an s3 object with `public-read` ACL, all the GET params are unnecessary.

I could cheat and use rewrite the URL without the GET params but that feels unclean and hacky.

How do I use boto3 to provide me with just the public link, e.g. `https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/my-key/my-object-name`? In other words, how do I skip the signing step in `generate_presigned_url`? I don't see anything like a `generated_unsigned_url` function.

Comment: Use virtual-hosted style S3 urls: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56090535/795876

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best solution I found is still to use the `generate_presigned_url`, just that the `Client.Config.signature_version` needs to be set to `botocore.UNSIGNED`.

The following returns the public link without the signing stuff.

```
config.signature_version = botocore.UNSIGNED
boto3.client('s3', config=config).generate_presigned_url('get_object', ExpiresIn=0, Params={'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': key})
```

The relevant discussions on the boto3 repository are:

- https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/110
- https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/169
- https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1415

Comment: You should include what config is defined to be: `s3 = boto3.client('s3')` and `config = s3._client_config`.

Comment: Absolutely. Or even cleaner, use `botocore.config.Config(signature_version=botocore.UNSIGNED)`