# How Do I get Object URL for Amazon S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, url, aws-sdk

I uploaded a file to my  Amazon S3 bucket and I would like to get a url using the aws-SDK not console for the object that I put in. The object has public read access
I have tried using

```
const url = s3Client.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
        Bucket: srcBucket,
        Key: key,
    });
```

but that generates a signed url that expires. I can't seem to find any other method to fetch just the url. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not aware of an API, generally, you can just construct it yourself:  `https://<bucket>.s3.<region>.amazonaws.com/<key>` or `https://s3.<region>.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/<key>` if your bucket name has periods or other characters invalid in a domain name.

Comment: See the answer by Julian Go here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64156936/495455

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3 Boto 3, AWS S3: Get object URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608570/python-3-boto-3-aws-s3-get-object-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case someone has a similar issue, like someone mentioned in the comment, as of the date this was written there isn't any API to get the s3 url without a signature except you construct it yourself. However, I found the following solution to be quick and easy to implement.

```
const signedUrl = s3Client.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: srcBucket,
    Key: key,
});
```

`signedUrl` returns in this format:

```
https://{org}.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/{PATH}/13592c51-d504-4899-960a-04efa0a7f6b7.mp3?AWSAccessKeyId={AWSKEY}&Expires={EPOC DATE}&Signature={RANDOMKEY-amz-security-}token=RANDOM&TOKEN}
```

To get an unsigned url (s3 Object url) you can split the string by the `"?"` query separator and return the first element which is identical to the Object url.

```
const url = signedUrl.split('?')[0];
// https://{org}.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/{PATH}/13592c51-d504-4899-960a-04efa0a7f6b7.mp3
```

The only consideration is if AWS changes the way s3 object urls are displayed in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the URL of an Amazon S3 object using the AWS SDK for Java V2. Here is the code:

```
// snippet-start:[s3.java2.getobjecturl.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetUrlRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import java.net.URL;
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.getobjecturl.import]

public class GetObjectUrl {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    <bucketName> <keyName> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    bucketName - the Amazon S3 bucket name.\n\n"+
                "    keyName - a key name that represents the object. \n\n";

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName =  args[0];
        String keyName = args[1];
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1 ;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        getURL(s3,bucketName,keyName);
        s3.close();
    }


    // snippet-start:[s3.java2.getobjecturl.main]
    public static void getURL(S3Client s3, String bucketName, String keyName ) {

        try {

            GetUrlRequest request = GetUrlRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(keyName)
                    .build();

            URL url = s3.utilities().getUrl(request);
            System.out.println("The URL for  "+keyName +" is "+url.toString());

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    // snippet-end:[s3.java2.getobjecturl.main]
}
```

Comment: `Property 'getObjectUrl' does not exist on type 'S3'.` I get this error when I try to use the method. It doesn't exist. Also im working with the aws-sdk for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is publicly accessible, you can construct the URL directly using this format:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/object-key